The 3.7 m dish antenna of Voyager
I need to know how Voyager-I was able to communicate with the base station on earth using the 3.7m dish antenna? Usually any dish antenna needs to be pointed towards the receiver and Voyager must be in random direction.


How many photons are received per bit transmitted from Voyager 1?

1:1 cross post from electronics.SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/724457/64158

From Wikipedia: "16 hydrazine thrusters, three-axis stabilization, gyroscopes and celestial referencing instruments (Sun sensor/Canopus Star Tracker) to maintain pointing of the high-gain antenna toward Earth."  It is remakable that they still work. More details are at the cited article.

My question is related to the dish antenna.

As your picture shows, the dish antenna is the high-gain antenna.
